# jruby/mysql: not enough memory for executing query

Tags: mysql, jdbc, jruby

i am using jruby 1.74 with the gem jdbc/mysql. The query is simple:

```
"Select id from Product"
```

This table contains ca. 7 500 000 entries. the result is that i get:

> "Error: Your application used more memory than the safety cap of
>   500M."

how can avoid this without increasing the memory size?

Comment: Don't fetch so many results in one query?

Comment: how can i fetch it? i am using "rsS = stmtSelect.execute_query("Select id from Product")"

Comment: But why do you want all this products at once?

Comment: i want to write all ids in a file

Comment: So get it in parts. It never makes sense to operate on such big amount of data at once.

Comment: how? with LIMIT in query?

Comment: Yes, with limit and offset. For export it'll be good enough.

Comment: ok, gonna try, but another question: how can i get the number of rows so that i know how many iterations are need

Comment: MySQL drivers (at least the JDBC driver, not sure if JRuby uses that) have the annoying habit to fetch all rows at once, instead of fetching in small blocks like most drivers do. For the MySQL JDBC driver there is a way to turn that off (set the fetchsize to `Integer.MIN_VALUE`), maybe a similar option is available in JRuby.